# Glossary does not print (with having multiple files) (Overleaf)

Tags: glossaries, overleaf

Following the basic example provided by latex: [Overleaf Glossary Example](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/glossaries), I was able to successfuly build a glossary that prints.

However, my issue is that the glossary doesn't print out when I have multiple files. I will demonstrate this below:

**General structure:**

[image: File Directory]

**Thesis.tex** (Compiled file)

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
        name=latex,
        description={Is a mark up language specially suited for 
scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
        name=mathematics,
        description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\newglossaryentry{formula}
{
        name=formula,
        description={A mathematical expression}
}

\newacronym{gcd}{GCD}{Greatest Common Divisor}

\newacronym{lcm}{LCM}{Least Common Multiple}

\begin{document}
\clearpage

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\printglossary

\input{Chapters/Introduction}
\end{document}
```

**Introduction.tex**

```
\chapter{Introduction}
The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. \Glspl{formula} are 
rendered properly an easily once one gets used to the commands.

Given a set of numbers, there are elementary methods to compute 
its \acrlong{gcd}, which is abbreviated \acrshort{gcd}. This 
process is similar to that used for the \acrfull{lcm}.
```

The introduction does print; however, the list of acronyms don't print. It is instead an empty page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! For problems that might be associated with the setup of your Overleaf project, consider getting in touch with Overleaf support: support@overleaf.com - they are happy to help answer these kinds of questions.

Comment: Hi Dan. Thank you for your reply. But I am not finding any difficulty in my project setup. I am missing something in my latex, I am not sure what it is.

Comment: In Overleaf, glossaries and indexes may not get generated correctly when you have your .tex file in a folder, rather than at the root (this is what I mean by project setup). Please consider reaching out to Overleaf support for more help with that.

Comment: Hello Dan. I do apologies from my end, it is my mistake. You're correct it had to do with the directory layout. I put my root file (thesis.tex) outside the folder it is in. I overlooked this. Thank you for your help!